# How can I make the value of a variable track the value of another

Tags: c#, .net, events

Here's a very simplified example of what I have now:

```
public static class Settings
{
    public static TH th;
}

public partial class PhrasesFrame
{
    private void SetC1Btn()
    {
        var a = (int)Settings.th;
        vm.C1BtnLabelTextColor = phrase.C1 == true ?
            Styles.A[(int)Settings.th] :
            Styles.A[(int)Settings.th];
    }
```

I would like to replace this with:

```
public partial class PhrasesFrame
{
    // The value of Settings.th can change at any time

    // I want the value of id to change when the 
    // value of (int)Setting.th changes. The way
    // it's coded now I realize it's just a one
    // time assignment

    var id = (int)Settings.th; 

    private void SetC1Btn()
    {
        var a = (int)Settings.th;
        vm.C1BtnLabelTextColor = phrase.C1 == true ?
            Styles.A[id] :
            Styles.A[id];
    }
```

Comment: `public int Id; public function PhrasesFrame() { Id = (int) Settings.th; }`?

Comment: If `Settings` (class?) can implement [INotifyPropertyChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.7.2), `PhrasesFrame` could subscribe it and change the value of `a` upon ACK.

Comment: @FrankerZ -  Sorry but I don't follow what's happening there.  You are creating a function but where would I use it? The PhrasesFrame class is created one time.  Would Id continually change to have the value of (int) Settings.th after that initial creation?

Comment: @jimi - I added the Settings class.  Could you give an example of what you mean as an answer if you think it's possible to do it the way you suggested. Thanks

Comment: I can. But, can `Settings` be extended, adding a Property which can raise the event?

Comment: @jim - yes it can be extended in any way.  I've added a snippet from the Settings class to let you know what it looks like.  It's just used to store values global to the application.

Comment: Ah, nope. I didn't notice that `Settings` is `static`. Can't implement an Interface here. I'll see if I can come up with something doable.

Comment: Implement either INotifyPropertyChanged or add a custom event handler which does the same. This is where WPF and databinding shines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This `Settings` class implements a custom `EventHandler` (`SettingsChangedEventHandler`), used to notify a property change to its subscribers:
You could setup a more complex custom `SettingsEventArgs` to pass on different values.

Changing the public `THProperty` property value raises the event:

```
public static class Settings
{
    public delegate void SettingsChangedEventHandler(object sender, SettingsEventArgs e);
    public static event SettingsChangedEventHandler SettingsChanged;

    private static TH th;
    private static int m_Other;

    public class SettingsEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public SettingsEventArgs(TH m_v) => THValue = m_v;
        public TH THValue { get; private set; }
        public int Other => m_Other;
    }

    public static void OnSettingsChanged(SettingsEventArgs e) => 
        SettingsChanged?.Invoke("Settings", e);

    public static TH THProperty
    {
        get => th;
        set { th = value; OnSettingsChanged(new SettingsEventArgs(th)); }
    }
}
```

The `PhrasesFrame` class can subscribe the event as usual:

```
public partial class PhrasesFrame
{
    private TH id;

    public PhrasesFrame()
    {
        Settings.SettingsChanged += this.SettingsChanged;
    }

    private void SetC1Btn()
    {
        var a = (int)this.id;
        //Other operations
    }

    private void SettingsChanged(object sender, Settings.SettingsEventArgs e)
    {
        this.id = e.THValue;
        SetC1Btn();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a simple and effective way to solve the problem. It is very similar to INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: @rolls  That was the intent. Since, in the comments, I proposed an event handler... Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @Jimi - Do I have to destroy the event that's been added to the PhrasesFrame at any point such as if PhrasesFrame is not referenced any more?

Comment: @Alan2  It would be better. `PhrasesFrame` could implement `IDisposable` and unsubscribe `Settings.SettingsChanged` in its `Dispose()` method. The structure of `Dispose()` depends on the managed/unmanaged resources that `PhrasesFrame` instantiates. About this: [Implementing a Dispose method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose). Eric Lippert's notorious series: [When everything you know is wrong](https://ericlippert.com/2015/05/18/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-one/).

Answer (score 2):

How about adding an Action to your static Settings class, and firing that action from the th setter?

I've used an int instead of your TH object, but I'm sure you can adapt the following example.

Test it here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ItaMhL

```
using System;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var id = (int)Settings.th;
        Settings.action = () => id = Settings.th;
        Settings.th = 123;
        Console.WriteLine(id);

        Settings.th = 234;
        Console.WriteLine(id);
    }

    public static class Settings
    {
        private static int _th;
        public static int th
        {
            get{return _th;}
            set{
                _th = value;
                action();}
        }

        public static Action action;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if he has 50 settings down the track? A simple action doesn't have a very clear intent. It also is limited to only a single listener. An event handler is a much better choice.

Comment: Of course, you are right. I've focused in this very specific example with only one value. But yes, to use this technique with 50 values would be a mess, for sure

Comment: Not everyone is interested in passing more parameters at once. This is a pretty good way of handling a single property value change.