# Passing data from Form B to Form A not working

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

**The Problem**
I have a program which opens up a new Form to the user for them to enter some data and after that I am trying to pass that data from that Form to the original Form.
For some reason I can't find a way to access the values through the handler. I went through documentations, similar SO questions but I ended up in despair and most likely made a mess.

**My attempt**

**Form A Part of Code**

```
private void addevid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form frm = new add_thing();

    if(frm.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        //do things while using the input
        Console.WriteLine(path); //for debugging reasons
    }
}
```

**Form B**

```
public partial class add_thing : Form
{
    public string piccpath1 { get; set; }
    public string piccpath2 { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string titlee { get; set; }

    public add_thing()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        path = piccpath1;
        path2 = piccpath2;
        description = desc;
        titlee = title;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string picpath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(picpath);
            string[] extract = Regex.Split(picpath, "evidence");
            string pipath2 = Regex.Replace(extract[1], "evidence", "");
            piccpath1 = picpath;
            piccpath2 = pipath2; 
        }
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        description = richTextBox1.Text;
        titlee = textBox1.Text;
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!
Cents

Comment: Note that you have inverted some assignments in the Form constructor: `path = piccpath1; path2 = piccpath2;` . Subscribe to the `frm.FormClosing()` event and read the public properties of `frm` in the event handler. Add the handler before `.ShowDialog()`, of course.

Comment: @Jimi So I should add a event handler on Form A, for the closing event in Form B?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Subscribe to the event in `FormA`, so when `FormB` is closed the event is raised and you can read the current values of `piccpath1` and `piccpath2`.

Comment: @Jimi I'm sorry but probably I'm blind at the moment. For some reason I can't find a way to access the values through the handler. Can you give me some direction on how to do this please?

Comment: All right, I'll write something down. Btw, you're passing empty strings in the constuctor of `FormB` (`string path, string path2, string desc, string title`). Were you trying to get something back from those or is there some other use that is not shown here?

Comment: @Jimi It was one of my attempts to retrieve the data through this method (which failed). I will remove it now as it wasn't the way as it seems.

Comment: You never define what does not work.  Based on `Form frm = new add_thing();`, my crystal ball thinks that you can not access the custom properties of the `add_thing` instance because you defined the variable `frn` as a `Form` and not as `add_thing`.  However, we should not have consult a crystal ball to learn stuff that you should include in your question.

Comment: @TnTinMn Ok, you made me realize the awfully stupid mistake that I did. Your crystal ball was right after all. There was no need to use any handlers...

Comment: Also, dispose `frm` when done.  That is another thing you missed when you "went through documentations".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible way, probably not the *greatest* one, to read the values of properties set in a Form (the Form named `add_thing`, here) from another Form (`FormA`).

Since, in `FormA`, you're creating a new instance of `add_thing`, you can subscribe to its `FormClosing()` event, which will be raised when the Form is about to close, before the `DialogResult` is set.
Note that the event is subscribed to using a Lambda: `frmAddThing.FormClosing += (obj, evt) => { }`.
You can, of course, use a standard event handler if you're not confortable with this syntax.

> I suggested the `FormClosing` event to handle this *exchange*, because
>   the `FormClosingEventArgs` gives you the chance to cancel the event,
>   so the Form won't close if required. Since the Dialog *doesn't know* how to use those paths, you have a second chance to show a notification, for example.

In the event handler, we can read the values of the public properties before the form is closed.
If the result of `add_thing` is `DialogResult.OK`, then do something with the updated values.

Another, probably better, way is to use the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) Interface to notify the subscribers that a property value has changed.
Or something similar, as you can see implemented in this question:
[How can I make the value of a variable track the value of another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52685685/7444103)

Anyway, these can be the modifications to apply to the current classes without changing much of what is already there:

In `FormA` (the caller):

```
public partial class FormA : Form 
{
    string frmAddThingPath1 = string.Empty;
    string frmAddThingPath2 = string.Empty;
    string frmAddThingDescription = string.Empty;

    private void addevid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        add_thing frmAddThing = new add_thing();

        frmAddThing.FormClosing += (obj, evt) => {
            this.frmAddThingPath1 = frmAddThing.piccpath1;
            this.frmAddThingPath2 = frmAddThing.piccpath2;
            this.frmAddThingDescription = frmAddThing.description;

            //If something is wrong with these paths, you can set 
            //e.Cancel = true and notify to 'start again'
        };

        ClearDialogResults();

        if(frmAddThing.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
            //On Form closed, do something with the results
            Console.WriteLine(this.frmAddThingPath1);
        }
        frmAddThing.Dispose();
    }

    private void ClearDialogResults()
    {
        frmAddThingPath1 = string.Empty;
        frmAddThingPath2 = string.Empty;
        frmAddThingDescription = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

In Form `add_thing`:

```
public partial class add_thing : Form
{
    public string piccpath1 { get; set; }
    public string piccpath2 { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string titlee { get; set; }

    public add_thing() => InitializeComponent();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
            string picPath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(picpath).Clone();
            string[] extract = Regex.Split(picpath, "evidence");
            string piPath2 = Regex.Replace(extract[1], "evidence", "");
            this.piccpath1 = picPath;
            this.piccpath2 = piPath2; 
        }
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.description = richTextBox1.Text;
        this.titlee = textBox1.Text;
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually thats good thing to learn. However, is my way somehow unsafe to use?

Comment: Sure, I hope it can be helpful :) The difference is that I'm using some fields to store the values returned by the Dialog. If you need to set these values *in place* and you don't need to access them anymore, it's the same thing. Remember to dispose of `add_thing` when you're done with it. Also you don't need `this.Close();` after you have set the `DialogResult`. The Form closes anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @TnTinMn for making me realise the stupid mistake, here is the functional code for anybody seeing this in the future:

**Form A Working Part of Code**

```
private void addevid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                       add_thing frm = new add_thing();          
            if (frm.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {                
                Console.WriteLine(frm.piccpath1); //It works!!
            }

        }
```

**Form B working code**

```
namespace CC_Case_Maker
{
    public partial class add_thing : Form
    {
        public string piccpath1 { get; set; }
        public string piccpath2 { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string titlee { get; set; }

        public add_thing()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string picpath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(picpath);
                string[] extract = Regex.Split(picpath, "evidence");
                string pipath2 = Regex.Replace(extract[1], "evidence", "");
                piccpath1 = picpath;
                piccpath2 = pipath2;

            }

        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            description = richTextBox1.Text;
            titlee = textBox1.Text;
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```