# How do I create a continuously updating Textbox that displays an updated subtotal as soon as an item has been added?

Tags: vb.net

I want to create a textbox that, when a new value is added to a variable (for example: `Price1` is assigned the value of 3.5), a textbox with the code

```
CheckP7_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles checkP7.TextChanged
        Dim subTotal As Double
        subTotal = (price1 * quant1 * taxRate) + (price2 + quant2 + taxRate)
    End Sub
```

would calculate the subtotal continuously until the user presses the checkout button. How would I go about doing this?

As far as I've tried, I can only get the textboxes to update when clicking a button saying "Calculate".

I expect the output to just continuously update the textbox with the current subtotal until the user hits either "Calculate" or "Checkout".

(e.g I have 2 hotdogs in the cart, each at a price of $2.5 . The subtotal shows $5 [before taxes], and I add a hamburger at $3.5 each. The subtotal is immediately updated to show the new price [$8.5])"

Comment: You can only execute code when an event is raised. That's how event-driven programming works. There's no event raised when a variable gets set. Of course, that variable is being set by code that must, itself, be being executed in or from an event handler, so that would be the place to update the `TextBox` too.

Comment: So create an event in the textbox. You should allow only numbers and decimal point to get entered. So also allow another character, say an A for add. As soon as the text changed event detects the A it adds the price etc and clears the textbox.

Comment: Using a class to handle the values, you have different options to handle property value changes. See both th answers here: [How can I make the value of a variable track the value of another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52685245/7444103). You can implement `INotifyPropertyChange` (as hinted in the answer here) or a simulation of it (my answer in the question I linked) or generate an action (the second answer there). Don't use stand-alone variables, use a *manager* class. Other options are available following these patterns. Property Binding is another common one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell by interpreting your current implementation, you are trying to achieve a real-time calculation/display on Winform/WPF -- correct me if i am wrong...

In general, you can achieve the real time calculation/display by handling the various events of the controls, but i would advise you to try create your won view/business models that implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface:
 * if any of the properties (like price, quantity, etc.) is changed, then raise a property changed event
 * and also raise a property changed event for the property of "Total"

and in your frontend, just bind all the fields to the various controls, with two way bindings.

so all the input at frontend will be taken into the object and causes a chain of updating, which would eventually result in the display of the total/sub-totals..

i believe you could find plenty of examples online...