# Having trouble firing an event in one form to be handled in another

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, events

We have an older WPF app that was written in VB.NET that has newer projects in C#. The main app (VB.NET) has a tab form that displays  newly opened user controls in separate tabs. Currently, the reference to the main tab form is being passed to other proejcts via tight coupling. This we are trying to remove.

Here is where I am stuck:

The main app has a form called AdminMain.xaml.vb

I added an event handler here like this:

```
Public Event OnOpenAccountOpeningPreviewEvent(accountOpeningPreview As AccountOpeningPreview)
```

The event handler itself looks like this:

```
Function OpenAccountOpeningPreview(accountOpeningPreview As AccountOpeningPreview)  Handles Me.OnOpenAccountOpeningPreviewEvent

    DIm oPreviewOnBoardingContentPane as ContentPane  = new ContentPane()
    Dim sPreviewOnBoardingName as string = "Preview OnBoarding Documents"

    oPreviewOnBoardingContentPane.Content = accountOpeningPreview

    oPreviewOnBoardingContentPane.Activate()

End Function
```

In the Loaded event of the AdminMain.xaml.vb user control I'm doing this:

```
Dim accountOpening = new AccountOpening()

AddHandler accountOpening.OnOpenAccountOpeningPreviewEvent, New AccountOpening.AccountOpeningPreviewEventHandler(AddressOf OpenAccountOpeningPreview)
```

In a separate project (C#) I have a user control called AccountOpening.xaml.cs that opens just fine in the tab because it is instantiated from the main VB.NET app. However, AccountOpening.xaml.cs needs to open AccountOpeningPreview.xaml.cs which is another C# user control in the same C# project as AccountOpening.

Here I have defined the event handlers like this:

```
public delegate void AccountOpeningPreviewEventHandler(AccountOpeningPreview sender);
public event AccountOpeningPreviewEventHandler OnOpenAccountOpeningPreviewEvent;
```

and when the AccountOpeningPreview user control is launched the code to do so looks like this:

```
AccountOpeningPreview accountOpeningPreview = new AccountOpeningPreview();
accountOpeningPreview.BOClientIdList = String.Join(",", BOClientIdList.ToArray());
accountOpeningPreview.FICode = _fi_code;
accountOpeningPreview.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

if (OnOpenAccountOpeningPreviewEvent != null)
    OnOpenAccountOpeningPreviewEvent(accountOpeningPreview);
```

One problem is that OnOpenAccountOpeningPreviewEvent is always null and cannot fire the event call that would raise the event in AdminMain (VB.NET project)

Its been a while since I've needed to do this so I'm probably missing something very simple.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Carl

Comment: You're missing a piece of the event handler, take it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52685685/7444103) (you need to invoke `OnOpenAccountOpeningPreviewEvent?.Invoke(this, e);`, of course. Maybe also change `OnOpenAccountOpeningPreviewEvent` to `OpenAccountOpeningPreviewEvent` and use the `On` prefix for the hadler itself). Also, verify that the UC's handle is already created when you `Invoke` the event (don't use the UC's constructor, that is).

Comment: Where do you hook up the event handler?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

In the main VB.NET app set up the event handler

```
Dim oViewControl As AccountOpening = New AccountOpening()

AddHandler oViewControl.Escalate, AddressOf OpenAccountOpeningPreview
```

and create the handler method:

```
Function OpenAccountOpeningPreview(sender As Object,e As UCEventArgs) 

    DIm oPreviewOnBoardingContentPane as ContentPane  = new ContentPane()

    oPreviewOnBoardingContentPane.Name = "PreviewOnBoardingDocuments"
    oPreviewOnBoardingContentPane.TabHeader = "Preview OnBoarding Documents"
    oPreviewOnBoardingContentPane.AllowDocking = true
    oPreviewOnBoardingContentPane.AllowFloatingOnly = true
    oPreviewOnBoardingContentPane.AllowClose = true
    oPreviewOnBoardingContentPane.Content = e.UCReference
    oPreviewOnBoardingContentPane.TabHeaderTemplate = CType(Resources("TabTemplate"), DataTemplate)

    DockGroup.Items.Add(oPreviewOnBoardingContentPane) //Using Infragistics tab

    oPreviewOnBoardingContentPane.Visibility = Visibility.Visible
    oPreviewOnBoardingContentPane.Activate()

End Function
```

In the C# project, create and event handler with an EventArgs object like this:

```
public class UCEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public AccountOpeningPreview UCReference { get; set; }

    public UCEventArgs(AccountOpeningPreview reference)
    {
        UCReference = reference;
    }
}

public event EventHandler<UCEventArgs> Escalate;

protected virtual void OnEscalate(UCEventArgs e)
{
    var handler = Escalate;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, e);
    }
}
```

Then, when the user presses the button to open the form, use this code to fire the event:

```
AccountOpeningPreview accountOpeningPreview = new AccountOpeningPreview();
accountOpeningPreview.BOClientIdList = String.Join(",", BOClientIdList.ToArray());
accountOpeningPreview.FICode = _fi_code;
accountOpeningPreview.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

OnEscalate(new UCEventArgs(accountOpeningPreview));
```