# .NET c# - how to pass aditional data to PropertyChangedEventHandler

Tags: c#, .net, event-handling

***I have this code :***

```
public void SomeMethod() 
{
    MyClass clss = new MyClass();    //note: MyClass implements INotifyPropertyChanged
    clss.DoSomething();
    clss.PropertyChanged += new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler(MyEventHandler);
}
static void MyEventHandler(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e) 
{
    Debug.WriteLine("some property on MyClass has changed!");
}
```

This is working ok and when the property in SomeClass changes, `MyEventHandler()` is run. 
But now I need to pass aditional data from `SomeMethod()` to `MyEventHandler()` , how can I do this?

*** UPDATE ***

ok I guess I should have explained better the whole problem: the method `DoSomething()` in `MyClass` makes a call to an external web service, passing it a callback so when the web service finish its work, it will call the callback, passing it a value with the result of the operation. Inside that callback, I am changing a property of the class to assign it the value received from the web service, thus triggering the `propertyChanged` event.
Then in the caller class, I subscribe to that event so I can do some things when it happens.

The final objective is, after calling `DoSomething()`, be able to wait until the web service has finished its job and returned a result, so I can then save some things in the database etc. and only then, return from `SomeMethod()`...

so this is MyClass, simplified:

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private long _wsReturnValue;
    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public long wsReturnValue 
    {
        get { return _wsReturnValue; }
        set {
            _wsReturnValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("wsReturnValue");
        }
    }
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name) 
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) 
            handler(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    } 

    public void DoSomething(object entity) 
    {
        //here I just call external web service and returns, the webservice will call TheCallback() when finished
    }

    public void TheCallback(CommunicationEventArgs e) 
    {
        this.wsReturnValue = e.res;
    }

}
```

And this is the class that uses MyClass:

```
class MainClass
{
    public void SomeMethod(object someObject)
    {
        MyClass clss = new MyClass();    //note: MyClass implements INotifyPropertyChanged
        clss.DoSomething(someObject);   //someObject contains data that I want to use later in the event handler
        clss.PropertyChanged += new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler(MyEventHandler);
    }

    private static void MyEventHandler(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //here I need to use the object someObject...
    }
}
```

Comment: What information do you need to pass? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You could implement your own version, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52685685/7444103).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is even close to what you mean, but here you go;

```
class EventClass
    {
        public void SomeMethod()
        {
            MyClass clss = new MyClass();    //note: MyClass implements INotifyPropertyChanged
            clss.DoSomething(new object());
            clss.PropertyChanged += new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler(MyEventHandler);
        }

        private static void MyEventHandler(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var customeEventArgs = (CustomEventArgs) e;
            Debug.WriteLine("some property on MyClass has changed! Extra Data : {0}", customeEventArgs.ExtraData);
        }
    }
```

Implemented some more shell code to illustrate

```
internal class MyClass
    {
        public void DoSomething(object data)
        {

            var e = new CustomEventArgs("Property")
            {
                ExtraData = data
            };

            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    }

internal class CustomEventArgs : PropertyChangedEventArgs
    {
        public CustomEventArgs(string propertyName) : base(propertyName)
        {
        }

        public object ExtraData { get; set; }
    }
```

Any help? :)

Comment: your solution could be ok , you create a custom event  to pass an extra parameter :).

Comment: thanks, I have tried it but I must be doing something wrong... please see my updated question with more info about the whole problem

Comment: @patsy2k from what i can see the changes you have made don't include using the "custom" event arguments class to carry the extra data?