# Understanding C# Event Handler: why no event?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, event-handling

Trying to get an event handler going, but more than that, understand the syntax behind these things. The following code compiles, I can see my DataGrid "SemesterView" inside Form1 but no event is triggered when the control SemesterView is entered, when I click on a cell, nuthin. What I am doing wrong? I've played around with other events in case I'm misunderstanding "Enter" but still nothing.

Within the form1 code

```
SemesterView semesterView;
semesterView = new SemesterView();
this.Controls.Add(semesterView);
semesterView.Enter += new SemesterView.EventHandler(semesterView.MyEvent1);
```

and in the SemesterView class

```
class SemesterView : DataGridView
{
        public delegate void EventHandler(string p);
        public   event EventHandler Enter;

        public SemesterView()
        {// code to create columns rows etc}


        public void MyEvent1(string p)
        { MessageBox.Show("event 1 works");}
}
```

Comment: Your event must have the right parameters. `public void MyEvent(object sender, System.EventArgs e)` it looks for a method with this signature. If one can't be found nothing happens.

Comment: Since you're inheriting `DataGridView`, attach the event in the constructor, after adding columns/rows. Expecting the consumer to attach the event handler breaks encapsulation.

Comment: @madreflection I agree, making that change does not solve the problem, it seems

Comment: No, definitely not. It was simply a review note. Josh and Joe H have your solution.

Comment: @Josh, adding those parameters to MyEvent1 results in compiler complaints that "no overload for MyEvent1 matches delegate SemesterView.EventHandler", even if I remove the "string p" parameter

Comment: [Simple code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52685685/7444103) to create an event with custom EventArgs  in a class and subscribe to the event in another class. Note that the DataGridView, deriving from Control, already exposes a public `Enter` event. Give the Event a name that is not *already taken*. The signature must be respected. Your class raises the event, the subscribers handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create a method that handles the event in SemesterView and tie the event to the handler:

```
class SemesterView : DataGridView
{
    public void MyEvent(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {

    }
}
```

Then in Form1

```
SemesterView semesterView;
semesterView = new SemesterView();
this.Controls.Add(semesterView);
semesterView.Enter += semesterView.MyEvent;
```

Comment: This works, if I delete the definitions of "EventHandler" and "Event" in SemesterView. I don't understand why though: this syntax seems to route around the syntax I see prescribed (using delegates etc etc). I guess the question remains what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Please mark as answered and upvote if that is the correct answer - Thanks Joe

Comment: Upvoted because the code you sent works, but still looking for what's wrong with my use of delegates. Thanks, G

Comment: Your event Enter is actually hiding the DataGridView.Enter event.  It's not doing anything.  DataGridView.Enter is already setup as a delegate on the base class and just needs the handler tied to it.