# Invoke of Eventhandler works on other machine but not on my own

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

I implemented an Eventhandler. Invoking it doesn't work on my machine. It works for my colleague with the exact same code.
What could be the reasons for this?

```
protected virtual void OnItemSelected()
    {
        ItemSelectedOrDeselectedEvent?.Invoke(this, new ItemSelectedEventArgs(this.FullPath, this.IsSelected, this.Type));
    }
```

the subscribed Method:

```
public void DoWorkMethod(object sender, ItemSelectedEventArgs args)
    {
        // Do work          
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "doesn't work".

Comment: Did you also define the `ItemSelectedEventArgs` derived (from `EventArgs`) class? Is there something that overrides and calls the `OnItemSelected` method, at some point (it's a `virtual` method...)? Can you give some more context to this code?

Comment: The only thing I could imagine here that could make that code "work" on one machine and on another fail is `this.FullPath`. You really need to add a stacktrace.

Comment: @JonSkeet This method gets called but it doesn't create a new ItemSelectedEventArgs. It just skips the invoke. If i remove the "?" it creates a new ItemSelectedEventArgs. but then System.NullReferenceException.

Comment: @Jimi 1) Yes. 2) No. 3) yes i will.

Comment: @Fildor I just don't understand why the same code behaves different.

Comment: Sounds like you've got nothing subscribed to the event. We can't tell how that would vary between machines, because we can't see any of the code that subscribed to it. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: If `ItemSelectedOrDeselectedEvent?` is skipped, then it's `null` (that's why the `EventArgs` object is not created and you have an exception when you remove the Elvis). Show the relevant code (plus the delegate).

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm 99.9% sure it's subscribed with += but i will try to add an example.

Comment: See whether the event generation pattern looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52685685/7444103) (unless you're using the `EventHandlerList` *style*).

Comment: I'm 100% sure it hasn't been *successfully* subscribed - or if it has, it's been unsubscribed. The handler not being subscribed perfectly explains the behavior of your method both with and without the null conditional operator. Perhaps you subscribed a handler to a different instance?

Comment: Ok...got a stupid iteration mistake where i subscribed to the method. Thanks for the help. The Reason why it worked for my colleague was that his target directory had no subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake:

```
var directorySubdirectories = new List<DirectoryInfo>(directory.EnumerateDirectories());

        var directoryFiles = new List<FileInfo>(directory.EnumerateFiles());

        // Create the view models from the data
        this.Items = new ObservableCollection<FileSystemInfoViewModel>();

        // Create DirectoryItemViewModels and subscribe to their event first folders then files
        for (int i = 0; i < directorySubdirectories.Count; i++)
        {
            this.Items.Add(new FileViewModel(directorySubdirectories[i]));
            this.Items[i].ItemSelectedOrDeselectedEvent += this.ScriptSelectedOrDeselected;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < directoryFiles.Count; i++)
        {
            this.Items.Add(new FileViewModel(directoryFiles[i]));
            this.Items[i].ItemSelectedOrDeselectedEvent += this.ScriptSelectedOrDeselected;
        }
```

I iterated over the same items in this.Items.
The colleague had no folders so it worked for him.