# How i can change signature of custom button c#

Tags: c#, winforms, events, signature, custom-button

I have my custom button:

```
public partial class RaiseEvent : Button
{

 public RaiseEvent()
{
 InitializeComponent();
}

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {}

}
```

And i need to change the signature like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, CatchEvent e)
{}
```

FULL EDIT :I have a DLL where are 2 class, one CatchEvent for customEvent:

```
public class CatchEvent : EventArgs
{
 public double data = 0;
 public CatchEvent(double value)
 {
 data = value;
 }
 public EventEnergy
 { 
 get { return this.data}
 }
}
```

And one class Calcul:

```
public class Calcul
{
 public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, CatchEvent e);
 public event EventHandler<CatchEvent> NewData;
 public void Event(double value, byte[] data)
{
 //some calculs = double result
 OnRaiseCustomEvent(new CatchEvent(result));
}
 public virtual void OnRaiseCustomEvent (CatchEvent e)
{
 raiseEvent(this.e);
}
```

With suggest in commentary for my Form:

```
public button1_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 double data = //i try to recover value from my class CatchEvent without legacy
 CatchEvent ce = new CatchEvent(data)
 textBox1.Text = ce.data.Tostring();
}
public Form1(Calcul pub)
{
 pub.NewData += button1; //doesnt work
}
```

So my last problem is to recover value from my class CatchEvent without class legacy.
Thanks you for help !

Comment: You are asking wrong question, see [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/299295). What are you trying to do in first place? Guessing from class name: you could create custom event and rise it from standard button click event handler.

Comment: You are asking the same question again and again. Should make you think.. - So once more: a Button is a Button and the Clicked signature cannot be changed. Period. You can call the event yourself and feed some params inherited from EventArgs in but the signature will not change! - Or you call whatever you want from the Clicked event. What data would be in your CatchEvent args?? Where would they come from?

Comment: @TaW So like i said again and again, my CatchEvent return me a double value from a DLL and i try to display value in textbox. The problem is i don't understand how you can call custom Event from a standard button.

Comment: Please avoid [re-asking same question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/473/299295).

Comment: So? You can code what you want in the Clicked event but it will stil be a Clicked event called by the system when the user clicks the Button. Where would you DLL come in? The signature is defined in the framework. - What exactly is CatchEvent? a structure or class or an actual event or delegate??

Comment: @Sinatr I did what you mean.

Comment: @TaW i edited post, my CatchEvent is a class. I did some test with a ConsoleProject and i got my value like i wanted so i think problem is only for recover value with button.

Comment: @NewCSharpWork Look, firstly you should express in detail about what your purpose is. In your statement, `my CatchEvent return me a double value from a DLL and i try to display value in textbox`. Well, how do you get this instance of your CatchEvent? If you generate it yourself, you can try to create a custom event, set it default and invoke it when the button is clicked. This can be done using `WndProc` or an override of `Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)` method. Or you can even make it easier by creating a custom property and setting the value when the button is clicked.

Comment: See the two examples here: [How can I make the value of a variable track the value of another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52685245/7444103). My code uses a custom Event and a custom `EventArgs` object to hand over data to subscribers when *something* changes, used to pass more than one value in a single call. The other uses an `Action`. You could use any of these.

Comment: Recovering should not be an issue: Simply cast the EventArgs to CatchEvent  - But to feed them in you need to do this: in your customButton class: `protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
{
    myEventArgs me = new myEventArgs(3.14d);
    base.OnClick(me);
}` - Use data from your DLL instead of my pi ! - Now you can use the data in your application like so `private void myButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myEventArgs me = e as myEventArgs;
    myButton1.Text = me.data + "+";
}` - Note that I used my own class names here.

Comment: I will try all your solutions, but for you @TaW i already try it but my data from DLL is unknow and i can't make a legacy from CatchEvent in custom button class. Note it can be done directly in ``` private void button1_Click (object sender, EventArgs){}``` without using a CustomeButton class.

Comment: Well if you can simply do it in the click event, the whole question seems unnecessary!?

Comment: @TaW no maybe i wasnt clear, but the problem i got in customButton is even in standard button, i just said this because an other guy tell me same answer in standard button.

Comment: Hm, if your event raiser already passes the vaild data then al you need is casting them as suggested : `CatchEvent catchEvent = (CatchEvent)e;`

Comment: @Taw Impossible to cast an object of type "System.Windows.forms.MouseEventArgs" into type "MyDLL.CatchEvent".

Comment: You need to inherit CatchEvent from EventArgs or maybe from MouseEventArgs of course. But in the code above you did just that : `public class CatchEvent : EventArgs...` -  If you can't do that you can't use the event paramters for your purpose. You can then try to store the data maybe in the Button.Tag object.

Comment: @TaW Thanks you for help , i will try to change method because its to hard for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you can't really change the signature, you can slip an expanded set of argument data into the event call if you use a custom Button class.

Here you provide an custom set of arguments in your custom button class by overriding the `Click` maybe like so :

```
protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e) 
{
    double data = // get data from DLL
    catchEvent ce = new catchEvent (data );
    base.OnClick(ce); 
}
```

Now you can access the data in your instance click events by casting the `EventArgs e` to your `CatchEvent` class:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CatchEvent catchEvent = (CatchEvent)e;
    Console.log(catchEvent.EventEnergy);
    button1.Text = catchEvent.data; 
}
```

Comment: The 1st part makes no sense to me. But: The 2nd part is half of the solution. But he will also have to make sure that an actual `CatchEvent` is coming in though `e`. See my comment above!

Comment: No problem~ please~

Comment: @Taw The whole question is turning around same problem. If i try to change signature of button since the start, it's for recover data from my customEvent and display it. At line `double data = //get data from DLL` you have solution, problem is solve.

Comment: If the problem is solved do consider accepting the answer; if you mean that it isn't because you can't get at the data at this line you need to explain when and where you can.. - Note that you still can't change the signature but you can slip in an expanded version of the Args.

Comment: @TaW yes sorry my "if" before "you have solution" has jump