# C# Can i associate several objects to one CustomEvent?

Tags: c#, events

If it's possible, how can i attribute several objects in one event.
Exemple like this:

```
public class CusEvent : EventArgs
{
 public double data1 = 0;
 public double data2 = 0;
 public CusEvent(double value, double value2)
{
 data = value;
 data2= value2;
}
```

And return 2 values.

Thanks you for help !

Comment: If you raise a custom event that uses your custom `EventArgs`,  subscribers can read those public Fields (maybe use properties instead). See here: [How can I make the value of a variable track the value of another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52685685/7444103), for example. Btw, you've asked the ~same thing a number of times.

Comment: @Jimi Sorry for my incompetence.

Comment: There's nothing to be sorry about. It makes one think that, possibly, you're not asking the right question. Anyway, try the code I linked. It's quite simple and you can see how it's implemented and used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class EventRaiser
{
    public delegate void CustomEventHandler(double data1, double data2);
    public event CustomEventHandler EventName;
}

public class EventListener
{
    public void EventName(double data1, double data2)
    {
    }
}
```

Somewhere in your listener class you should have: `EventRaiser.EventName += this.EventName`

Comment: Not really what i try to do. My event is working, its only for dispatch value in different textbox after two calls of my event.

Comment: @NewCSharpWork I don't understand what you're trying to do then. This allows you to "return" 2 values like you asked.