# How to trigger a method in a form and pass parameters to that from another class in C#?

Tags: c#, class, process

I have a separate class (named as `python`) that runs Python with Process in C# app. The class has three methods that get triggered based on messages from the process (on error or completion) in addition to messages from my python script. I want to update a method in calling (parent class, like a form) class with messages coming from the `python` class that runs the Python. The method in the calling class may update the messages on a form or save messages. (multiple calling classes for the python class)
How could I create the `python` class in any calling class that needs to read messages from the python class?

[I followed the following example :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52685245/how-can-i-make-the-value-of-a-variable-track-the-value-of-another/52685685#52685685)

Python class setup :

```
namespace PGPython
{
    class Python
    {
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52685245/how-can-i-make-the-value-of-a-variable-track-the-value-of-another/52685685#52685685

        public delegate void PythonMessageEventhandler(object sender, MessageEventArgs e);
        public static event PythonMessageEventhandler sendPythonMessage;

        public static void OnPythonMessages(MessageEventArgs e)
        {
            sendPythonMessage?.Invoke(null, e);
        }

        public Python()
        {
            AppSettings set = new AppSettings();
            Utilities util = new Utilities();
            set = util.GetAppSettings();

            pythonEXEPath = set.PythonEXEPath;
            ContourPython = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath), "\\Python\\contour.py");
            CirclePython = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath), "\\Python\\circle.py");
        }
```

On the parent form :

```
    private void updateCommandText(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        //string message = e
       txtCommand.AppendText(e.message + Environment.NewLine);
    }

 private void DoSolderJointWidthMeasurements(string saveDataFile, string ImageFile, RawBGAXrayParameterFiles Cordinates)
        {
            Python SJW = new Python();
            SJW.**sendPythonMessage** += updateCommandText;
........
```

However, I can not see the "sendPythonMessage" method in SJW instance. How do I fix it ? Error I get is :

```
Error   CS0176  Member 'Python.sendPythonMessage' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead    SJW_metrology_client
```

Comment: Just create one instance of the python class and make sure all object use the one instance of the class.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not.

Comment: Why not.  You can pass the instance between classes/methods.  See my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: Thank you for the above link. In my case, it's not between two forms. In Form1, I could have Python p = new Python(). So I need to get messages from the p instance of Python class when events get triggered inside the Python class. In Form2, I could have again Python p = new Python(). This is a separate instance that should do the same as Form1 but in Form 2. They are independent. I

Comment: Add public events that any other class (Form or whatever) can subscribe to. Raise the events when the related Process events are raised. Should this *python class* be static? Do you mean to create multiple instances of this class?

Comment: Yes, multiple instances of the Python class

Comment: Well, you'll have to test if you can run that script concurrently. In any case (except a static version of that class, which would change some details), you can use the events as described. Or implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and set public properties when the Process' events are raised. It's a just a slightly different implementation.

Comment: Something like this, for example, with a static class: [How can I make the value of a variable track the value of another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52685685/7444103) (see also the other answer). If the class is not static, you can implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` directly and it's the same thing. Subscriber are notified when one or more property values change. The current values are passed to subscribers using an `EventArgs`-derived object. It's quite simple to setup an maintain (IMO). Events can be used in any case.

Comment: Note that you could also have the consumers pass an `IProgress<T>` object as a variant: it can use both an event and an `Action<T>` delegate. It may require a little more work if you want to handle all the Process' events at the same time with different handlers. Also note that the Process raises events in worker threads without a `SynchronizingObject`. If you dont't want to force the subscribers to pass a sync object (or `BeginInvoke()` to their thread), in this case `Progress<T>` comes in handy.

Comment: I have never done this so it's challenging to me. This is what I followed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/. This works very fine as far as I don't pass data to the event. But still, I don't understand how to pass data to event.

Comment: Hi Jim1, your link is the best so far. When I set "public static event PythonMessageEventhandler sendPythonMessage;" in Python class, I can not access the method in Parent class.any reason for that ?

Comment: First thing, given your description, don't make the event static, just public. Then classes that create an instance of your *python class* need to subscribe to the event, as usual. I assume you've added the `PythonMessageEventhandler` delegate. This is useful if you have also defined your own `EventArgs`-derived class. A subscriber can then initialize your class as, e.g,: `var pythonClass = new PythonClass(); pythonClass.sendPythonMessage += this.OnSendPythonMessage;`, where `OnSendPythonMessage` is the event handler used to receive the events. Or use a Lambda.

Comment: How do I do PythonMessageEventhandler delegate and where ?

Comment: Its working . . . . ! Thank you Jimi for your supports. I would have not done without your help . . . . . ! Thank you again.

Comment: Well, I'm glad it helped :) Possibly, collect the code your wrote and package it as an answer you can post here.